# Select all tables with at least one row of data inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want return all tables that have at least one row of data.

I was using this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)) 
FROM SYS.DM_DB_PARTITION_STATS ST
WHERE ST.ROW_COUNT > 0 AND OBJECT_ID > 100
```

But I don't want use the table `SYS.DM_DB_PARTITION_STATS`.

I want to know another way to find these tables?

Any clues?

thanks.

Comment: ***WHY*** do you want to not use `sys.dm_db_partition_stats`?? Any particular reason?

Comment: "I want to know another way to find these tables?", A Procedure using sysobjects and iterating though each table... using dynamic sql and a loop Amend results to temp table and select form it, or keep track another way.  but iterating though and Dynamic SQL is only way I can think of outside of system objects.

Comment: @xQbert no, please, not `sysobjects`, it's a deprecated, backward-compatibility view that you should definitely not recommend to people.

Comment: Not a particular reason, I'm just curious. Dont know why people voted negative.. I dont think its a dumb question.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx sys.objects is part of the catalog view that MSFT supports in future versions... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783.aspx  but perhaps it was just my missing . ... sysobjects *(Bad) vs sys.objects (Good)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not use sys.dm_db_partition_stats

Answer (score 8):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
WHERE 
    t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND p.rows > 0
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

That would list all tables with the name and number of rows (> 0) in them.

And it **doesn't** use `sys.dm_db_partition_stats`  ....

Comment: Thanks Marc_s! Nice one.

Comment: @issues Still not following why `sys.partitions` is good but `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` is bad. For row counts they both get their information from the same place (they just have different information if you're looking for other details).

Comment: Read again and try see where I wrote its bad use 'sys.dm_db_partition_stats'. I just wanted to know another way. stop complain for nothing please.

Comment: @issues, this should be marked as the answer and not AndreDuarte's answer.